# How to set Vim's Minimum split size

Tags: vim, split

When I maximize a split inside vim, the other splits get a height of 1 line. In the past, I've been able to enjoy a minimum split size of 0 (it was a different vim version & build, I guess).

How can I configure vim so that when maximizing a split, all of the other splits get a height of 0? (I like it when the only thing showing in the splits is the filename, and none of the contents).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to

```
set winminheight=0
```

See [`:help winminheight`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27wmh%27)